# If host is not devlopment site show google analytics on wp_header

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

The idea of the following code is to display google code for analytics only if the website is not the development site- So I put it on my child-theme under Wordpress but something does not working.

Any idea where is my mistake ?

```
add_action('wp_header', 'add_googleanalytics');

function add_googleanalytics()
{
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==="mywebsite.com" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==="www.mywebsite.com") 
    {
        if (@$_COOKIE["COOKIENAME"] !== "COOKIEVALUE")
        {?>
     <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

          ga('create', 'GOOGLE ID', 'auto');
          ga('send', 'pageview');
         </script>
    <?php
    }
    }
}
```

Also and it's probably important:

I do dev my web site in local with XAMPP and sync the online website via a wp plugin "wp-sync-db-master" which duplicate with online adress all local change on my website...

it means that I CAN'T use any code specific to my local website because it will be replicate to the online website. So the code must detect if he is online or not to detect if google analytics must be on or off.

...hope you will understand.

Comment: Why not filter it on GA?

Comment: Theres various possible reasons: but lets start with some more information about what isn't working please, is the hook firing?, are you definitly running the child theme?, consider using the WP function get_site_url() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/ and maybe even use Google Tag Manager to implement GA with firing rules for the urls

Comment: And with your update it's even easier to filter it on GA. Just add your IP as a filter out. Don't make it harder than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way in WordPress to distinguish the environment it is running against is setting the `WP_DEBUG` to a **Boolean** value.

Such option can be define in the `wp-config.php` file in your root directory, code as follows:

```
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

And in your action hook, you can define a conditional statement; that only load the GA script if it's in production mode.

```
if(WP_DEBUG === false) {
    // Google Analytics goes here.
}
```

Comment: I just edit my question to add some important notes...but will try your solution.

Comment: `wp-config.php` file is ignored when pushing codes to the server from local development. Live server might have specific configurations stored in `wp-config.php` that local environment might find unusable.

Comment: @BaliAngeloCogerino if you find the solution helpful, you can mark this answer as accepted.